# Random long, can it be twice in a row the same number

Tags: java, random

I was wondering with the current java 1.7 implementation of the Random class, is it possible for the code below to generate two times the same random long?

```
Random rand = new Random((long) "some seed".hashCode());
while(rand.nextLong() != rand.nextLong()){

}

System.out.println("Will this text ever be on the console?");
```

Java source for nextLong() and next();

```
public long nextLong(){
    return ((long) next(32) << 32) + next(32);
}

protected synchronized int next(int bits){
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

I would answer this question with false because I think the random method used by java does not repeat the same numbers for a 2^48 period, so it would never generate two the same numbers in a row. Is this correct?

Comment: It theoretically is possible. You have a 1:281,474,976,710,656 (2^48) chance of getting a particular number. That means you have a 1:79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,336 ((2^48)^2) of getting the same number twice (or any individual set of two numbers, technically). So, theoretically, yes. You may have to run that loop for centuries before it breaks, but it will eventually happen.

Comment: So it could happen when the program has enough time to execute? (In theory)

Comment: I suspect you are right that the pseudo-random algorithm of rand.nextLong will never produce two identical values in a row, unless reseeded.  But the same would not be true for a "real" RNG, or a PRNG that derives its values differently.

Comment: @Deactivator2 - Rolf's thinking is that the algorithm is a *pseudo* random number generator, and if the long value is essentially the main value stored internal to the generator, it will never repeat, for the cycle time of the pseudo-random algorithm.  I suspect that he is *probably* right, though one would need to inspect the innards of the algorithm to be sure.

Comment: This is an oldie but a goodie: http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~irjohnso/coursenotes/ufeen8-15-m/p1192-parkmiller.pdf

Comment: @RolfSmit In theory, yes, but as Hot Licks mentions, we'd have to see the actual algorithm.

Comment: @HotLicks Disregard this comment, I believe you're actually right. I mistakenly assumed `seed` wasn't carried over for some reason, but the value persists through each call to `next()`. In this case, I do believe it is impossible to generate the same value twice, unless there was a literal single value that fit into that seed equation that would spit out the same value.

Comment: Not sure if I really understand "see the actual algorithm" is there more than the source methods I posted? I got something to read I guess ;) @Deactivator2 I have the same thoughts, but is there no mathematical way to proof something like this?

Comment: @RolfSmit I think he means actually taking that algorithm and running it through some real values, since this appears to be all there is to it. Mathematically, I can't really think of a way to prove it besides a ton of trial and error, or trying to find a very specific value of `seed` that would break it. Which, of course, may not even exist.

Comment: @Deactivator2 - The algorithm repeatedly modifies `seed`, generating the next value from the previous one.  A long value is produced from two successive 32-bit values, however, and the 32-bit values are produced from what are apparently 48-bit values with (hopefully) a cycle time of about 2**48.  So there's in theory a chance that the algorithm could produce two values whose low-order 32 bits are the same in quick succession (though I suspect that the specifics of the algorithm prevent this).  IOW, a mathematician might be able to prove a chance of repeat, but no mortal programmer could.

Comment: @HotLicks nice thinking! +1 for "but no mortal programmer could". I'm really starting to think this question should get some attention from the math.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: @HotLicks Well said, and I agree with your conclusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To come up with an "longer" answer than my previous:

You already linked the implementation, it looks like:

```
public long nextLong(){
    return ((long) next(32) << 32) + next(32);
}
```

So, obviously, ONE random number calls 2 times `next(32)`.
That means, 2 random numbers will be equal, if `next(32)` results
in 4 times THE SAME number because the rest of the function is "hardcoded".

Looking at the `next()` function, we can see the following:

```
protected synchronized int next(int bits){
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

The return part can be simply ignored, because again: SAME seed would lead
to the SAME return value - otherwhise your CPU is broken.

So, in total: We only need to focus on the line

```
seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
```

if that will result in the SAME seed, for **four times**, 2 random numbers have been generated,
that are equal.

(***Note: Sequences like a,b,a,b can be excluded to produce the same result. Post is long enough, i skip that part.)***

---

First, lets eliminate the `<< 48` part. What does that mean? The Number given (1) will be shifted left
48 times. So the binary `0...01` will turn into `1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (48 zeros)
then, one is subtracted, so what you will get is `0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` (47 ones)

Lets have a look at the first part of that equation:

```
(seed * 0x5DEECE66D[L] + 0xB[L])
```

**Note, that the ending [L] will only cause it to be a long value instead of a integer.**

so, in binary words, that means:

```
seed * 10111011110111011001110011001101101 + 1011
```

After all, the function looks like

```
seed = (seed * 10111011110111011001110011001101101 + 1011) & (0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
```

(I left out the leading zeros on the first values)

So, what does `& (0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)` do ?

The bitwise-and-operator and basically compares EVERY position of two binary numbers. And only if BOTH of them are "1", the position in the resulting binary number will be 1.

this said, EVERY bit of the equation `(seed * 10111011110111011001110011001101101 + 1011)` with a position GREATER than 48 from the RIGHT will be **ignored**.

The 49th bit equals `2^49` or `562949953421312 decimal` - meaning that & `(0111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)` basically just says
that the **MAXIMUM** result can be `562949953421312 - 1`. 
So, instead of the result `562949953421312` - it would produce 0 again, `562949953421313` would produce 1 and so on.

**All the stuff I wrote above could be easily verified:**

While the following code will produce the random **seed** **11**:

```
private Long seed = 0L;

protected synchronized int next(int bits){
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    System.out.println(seed);
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

One can reverse engineer the seed and ALSO gets the seed 11 from a non-0 seed, using the number `562949953421312L`.

```
private Long seed = 562949953421312L - 0xBL / 0x5DEECE66DL;

protected synchronized int next(int bits){
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    System.out.println(seed);
    return (int) (seed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

So, you see: **Seed 562949953421312 equals Seed 0**.

Easier proof:

```
Random r = new Random(0L);
Random r2 = new Random(562949953421312L);

if (r.nextLong()==r2.nextLong()){
    System.out.println("Equal"); //You WILL get this!
}
```

it continous of course:

```
Random r3 = new Random(1L);
Random r4 = new Random(562949953421313L);

if (r3.nextLong()==r4.nextLong()){
    System.out.println("Equal");
}
```

Why is this "magic number" (`562949953421312L`) important?

Assuming, we are starting with Seed 0.

The the first new-seed will be: `0 * 10111011110111011001110011001101101 + 1011 = 1011 (dec: 11)`

The next seed would be: `1011 * 10111011110111011001110011001101101 + 1011 = 100000010010100001011011110011010111010 (dec: 277363943098)`

The next seed (call 3) would be: `100000010010100001011011110011010111010 * 10111011110111011001110011001101101 + 1011 = 10000100101000000010101010100001010100010011100101100100111101 (dec 2389171320405252413)`

So, the maximum number of `562949953421312L` is exceeded, which will cause the random number to be SMALLER than the above calculated value.

Also, adding `1011` will cause the result to alternate between odd and even numbers. (Not sure about the *real* meaning - adding 1 could have worked as well, imho)

So, generating 2 seeds (NOT random numbers) ensures, that they are NOT equal, because a specific "overflow" point has been selected - and adding the MAXIMUM value (562949953421312L) is NOT enough to hit the same number within 2 generations.

And when 2 times the same seed is impossible, 4 times is also impossible, which means, that the nextLong() function could never return the same value for n and n+1 generations.

**I have to say, that I wanted to proof the opposite. From a statistical point of view, 2 times the same number is possible - but maybe that's why it's called Pseudorandomness :)**

Answer (score 5):

No, getting two identical longs in a row with this algorithm is impossible.

While people were writing long posts about math and other wizardry, I went the code monkey route and brute forced the 2^48 possible seeds over the weekend. No two longs produced in a row were ever equal for any seed.

---

```
long int seed = 0;

int next(int bits){
    seed = (seed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    return (int) (seed >> (48 - bits));
}
long int nextLong(){
    return ((long int) next(32) << 32) + next(32);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  long int step = atoi(argv[1]);
  long int i = step << 32;
  long int end = (step+1) << 32;
  while(i < end) {
    seed = i;
    if(nextLong() == nextLong()) {
      printf("Found seed %ld\n", i);
      return 0;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  printf("No seed in %ld\n", step);
  return 1;
}
```

then

```
echo {0..65535} | xargs -n 1 -P 12 ./executable
```

Comment: @MooingDuck It tests every pair. You'll notice it wouldn't compare `0,1`, `1,2`, `2,3`, etc, just `0,1`. The following sequence is determined solely based on the current seed, so if there is a seed that produces `0 1 1 2 2..`, there is also a seed that produces `1 1 2 2..`, and `1,1` would be caught there. Checking the first pair of each seed is equivalent to checking every pair of the sequence produced by each seed.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't read your code thoroughly enough, should work fine.  I assumed you were using a different algorithm that looks vaguely similar, but should run about twice as fast.

Comment: Neat. Which algorithm?

Comment: `long prev=nextLong(); for(long i=0; i<LONG_MAX; ++i) { long cur=nextLong();if(cur==prev)return i;cur=prev;}`.  Only calls `nextLong` once per seed instead of twice.

Comment: Then again, I still haven't figured out what `step` is for, are your running this in parallell?  That's a good idea too.  Wait, aren't there 2^64 possible seeds?

Comment: You can see from the algorithm that the seed is truncated to 48 bits. What will your algorithm do if it encounters a cycle, e.g. an infinite series of `0,1,2,0,1,2,..`?

Comment: I see from the algorithm that only the _top_ 48 bits of the seed are used to generate each individual random number.  However, the full 64bits of _state_ are all used.  The question is not about cycles, and neither my code nor yours will detect cycles.

Comment: The algorithm uses the top 32 bits of the lower 48 bits to generate an int (and two ints for a long). Neither algorithm detects cycles, but for this one it doesn't matter while yours will keep looping the cycle rather than checking new seeds.

Comment: Mine simply generates 1.8446744e+19 random numbers in a row checking for sequential duplicates, there's no looping of state that would occur.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55022/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-that-other-guy).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which question you're asking.

As others have said: The standard formulas for pseudo-random number generators fully explore their value space before repeating.

However: In most applications we don't use the full range of the PRNG's output. We reduce it by dividing or truncating it down to a range that matches the problem we're trying to solve. And most of the ways we do so will, in fact, result in a series of numbers which can include immediate repeats.

And that could be true even if you're simply using an integer random number when the underlying formula is using more bits for its calculations.

So: Theoretically, if you're looking directly at a PRNG's output, the answer is "probably not". Practically, the answer is "don't count on it either way."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  I believe that the generator uses the next number as the seed for the subsequent number.  So, if you get a value once, and if it were to repeat, your number generator would be stuck in a loop.

However, many applications are looking for a number in a certain range, which makes it possible to repeat since a subsequent number may have the same value modulo the range.

**EDIT**: Since you included the source code of `next` you can see that if ever it returned the same number, it would always return the same number.  Hence, you'd be stuck in a loop of one value.