# Will rand() sometimes return the same consecutively?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, random

I'm just curious, can a single-threaded program ever get the same return value for two consecutive calls to `rand()`?

So, will this assertion ever fire?

```
assert(rand() != rand());
```

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: For a good RNG this assert may fail, but some PRNGs generate sequences where there is no repetition, in which case it would always pass.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see some code at works use the `rand()` return as a unique id for some logic, I thought it would be fail sometimes, but not sure rand() will return same value.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21634465/3235496 (it's a java-question but brings up valid points).

Comment: You can cast a die twice and get six each time, no?

Comment: Do you mean *consecutively*? If so, then it might be good to put that in the title. And remove the "special seed" thing. That is  just confusing.

Comment: Returning only unique numbers is a *pattern* and is not *random* as such.

Comment: "Will rand() some times return same value consecutively?" - yes.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is a desirable property of software RNGs that they are "random". However, many are not by even simple measures such as whether sequential repetition is truly possible, and analogies with truly random systems don't always hold. The internal implementation matters. There are good and bad RNGs, and languages with longer pedigrees may have quite bad built-ins (for backwards-compatibilty when using seeds). If you are interested, you could take a look at http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php which has an implementation of `rand()` that flunks a lot of tests.

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: Using `rand()` as a unique id is not what I would consider a good choice.  What's wrong with a simple sequential count for the id?

Comment: @juanchopanza Of course. But, to paraphrase Einstein, `rand()` does not play dice.

Comment: @SChepurin `rand()` is not random, as such: it's pseudorandom.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Version 4 [universally unique identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/universally_unique_identifier) requires using a random number, not a simple sequential count.

Comment: If it wasn't possible, it wouldn't be random (pseudo or otherwise). Consider the degenerate case of a binary random outcome (like flipping a coin). If it were not true the consecutive generated results could be the same, the only sequence possible is an alternating sequence - definitely *not* "random".

Comment: Depends on the implementation :P Conside for example http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @DavidCary The op never mentioned UUIDs, but surely all numbers between 0 and whatever the largest 122 bit number is are all valid values to create a type 4 UUID.  If, as was implied in the comment, the random value is being used for a unique id inside a single program a simple counter guarantees uniqueness and no other solution does.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If we can find one example where it does, the answer to your question is "yes".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  unsigned int i;
  for(i = 0; ; i++) {
    int r = rand();
    if (r == rand()) {
        printf("Oops. rand() = %d; i = %d\n", r, i);
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

prints `Oops. rand() = 3482; i = 32187` on Windows with Visual Studio 2010.

EDIT:
Use the version below to detect all sequences where 2 consecutive rand() calls return the same value.
C only specifies that rand() should return "pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to
RAND_MAX" and RAND_MAX should be at least 32767.
There are no constraints on the quality of the PRNG, or it's implementation, or other details such as whether 2 consecutive rand() calls can return the same value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  unsigned int i;
  int r1 = rand();
  int r2 = rand();
  for(i = 0; ; i++) {
    if (r1 == r2) {
        printf("Oops. rand() = %d; i = %d\n", r1, i);
    }
    r1 = r2;
    r2 = rand();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @bits_international because it came later and unwind's answer was everyone's first impulse.

Comment: @bits_international: The definition in the manual or standard is more authoritative than the result of a program execution. For all we know (without reference to an actual definition of `rand()`), this behavior could be a bug in the visual studio implementation, or the program could have undefined behaviour.

Comment: From nwp's and Gohan's answer it follows that you should not use this random generator. Don't think it really is the answer the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Zane: How do you figure?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but it looks like this could miss a lot of random consecutive numbers. It only checks if an odd call is the same as the next even one, not that an even call is the same as the next one one. You found one eventually but there's a good chance there's an earlier case.

Comment: On Ubuntu 64 bit (amd64), with gcc 4.6.3, rand() will repeat 1804289383 after 2888000745 iterations.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, but -- what Hovercouch is saying is that although nos's code would detect the `0 0` in `0 0 7`, it would not detect the `3 3` in `1 3 3 7`.

Comment: @Mankarse: This program demonstrates that the answer to the OP's question is "yes": the OP asked if it can ever happen, and this answer demonstrates that it can. The OP did not ask about whether that behavior was allowed by the standard. Even if this were a bug in MSVC, it would still answer the question. (Of course, it would also be useful for the answer to state that this was a bug, if it were.)

Answer (score 31):

#### I did my research

discovered that my compiler(`msvc10`)'s rand implementation did use Linear congruential generator just like other c/c++ compiler

#### Linear congruential generator

Linear congruential generator use the recurrence method.

[image: use the]

ptd->_holdrand(n) will never equals ptd->_holdrand(n+1), but the mod result will equal.

#### msvc implemention

@nos shows the result

```
return( ((ptd->_holdrand = ptd->_holdrand * 214013L + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff );

ptd->_holdrand = 2375716238;
return 3482; (2375716238 >> 16) % 32768
ptd->_holdrand = 228240921;
return 3482; (228240921 >> 16) % 32768
```

final answer is the rand() will return same value twice some times as my instinct.

Comment: It's nice that you did your research, but that's often the step _before_ posting a question (a rule that almost no one on stackoverflow abides by).

Comment: +1 for supplementing your own question with some math as an answer. Like @Shahbaz said, it's best to do this kind of research before the question, to avoid *needing to ask* if you find what you were looking for, but it's good to have reference questions like these on SO (in my opinion) anyway.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice, That's true. The best thing to do would be this: do research (in the process possibly find out that no question in SO answers you). If you don't find your answer, ask question. If you do find your answer, ask the question anyway and post your response to help others (you can post a question and its answer at the same time!). Reap rewards for a well-researched question (and possibly well-written answer).

Comment: But then quite often the answers give a hint what research to do, so without reading the answers to the question an attempt at research would have failed. Sometimes answers give an incomplete answer, and the questioner, more interested in the complete answer than everyone else, can use this as a start. Posting an improved answer benefits everyone. And research after posting is miles better than no research after posting.

Comment: @Shahbaz I disagree. I think that if a question is likely to generate information that's helpful to other users, it's fine to post it, as long as it isn't a duplicate. This is definitely such a question.

Comment: @Shahbaz unless you want to farm some reputation ;)

Comment: The important part here being that the lower 16 bits of the PRNG's internal state aren't used in the output.  This makes it possible to repeat the output without repeating the internal state.

Comment: @kevin, we are saying the same thing. As I said, even if you find your answer by doing your research, it's still a good idea to post the question and answer it yourself, exactly for the reason you are saying.

Comment: @mattmcnabb, I didn't get why there is an "unless". In both cases I said it's better to ask the question and both cases generate well-deserved reputation.

Answer (score 9):

A ideally random `rand()` function, if called twice, would return the same result each time with a probability of `1.0 / RAND_MAX`.

But `rand()` is not a true random number generator.  It's a [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) (PRNG), typically of the [linear congruential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) type.

The *internal state* of the PRNG must not be repeated on consecutive calls; if it did, `rand()` would get stuck on the same number forever.  This can happen with poorly-designed algorithms like the [middle square method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method).

However, some (but not all) PRNG implementations have more bits in their internal state than they have in their output.  For example, `java.util.Random` uses a 48-bit internal state but only includes the most significant 32 bits in its output.  In this case, it's (at least theoretically) possible to get the same output two consecutive times without having the same internal state.

Answer (score 6):

A good random number generator *should* sometimes return the same value twice in a row. Let's say it returns positive integers 0 <= r < 2^31. The chance that two consecutive numbers are the same would be about one in two billion for a perfect random number generator. The chance of *not* getting two consecutive numbers that are the same in 100 billion calls is about one in 10^15.

Comment: until you use randomize() with rand/random (), right? randomize() func is a separate one that I have used in past whenever I wanted random/rand() to return me a pure random number. Again, you still have the probability to get the same # but it's rare.

Comment: @ArunSangal depends on what you are using it for, what you are seeding with.